# I am fetching token count from users table in supabase but does not appear straight away in the navbar when i login only after refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, supabase

```
import HomePage from '../HomePage/HomePage';
import LandingPage from '../LandingPage/LandingPage';
import AuthPage from '../AuthPage/AuthPage';
import MyAccountPage from '../MyAccountPage/MyAccountPage';
import NavBar from '../NavBar/NavBar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css'
import supabase from '../../supabaseClient';

 export type TableResults = {
  item_id: string;
  created_at: string;
  title: string;
  image: string;
  user_id: string;
  username: string;
  token_count?: number;
}


export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<TableResults[]>([]);
  const [filteredItems, setFilteredItems] = useState<TableResults[]>(items);
  const [user, setUser] = useState<any>(null);
  const [tokenCount, setTokenCount] = useState<number|null>(null);


  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredItems(items);
  }, [items]);

  async function getItems() {
    let { data: itemsData, error: itemsError } = await supabase
      .from('items')
      .select('item_id, created_at, title, image, user_id');

    let { data: usersData, error: usersError } = await supabase
      .from('users')
      .select('user_id, username, token_count');

  

      if (itemsError) console.error('Items Error: ', itemsError);
      if (usersError) console.error('Users Error: ', usersError);
      
      if (!itemsError && !usersError && itemsData && usersData) {
        const transformedData = itemsData.map(item => {
          const user = usersData?.find(user => user.user_id === item.user_id);
          return {
            ...item,
            username: user ? user.username : null,
          };
        });
      
        console.log('Transformed Data: ', transformedData);
        setItems(transformedData);
      }
  }

// this is to check that the items are being pulled from the database
console.log("see items below...")
console.log(items)

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchUserTokenCount = async () => {
    console.log('Fetching user token count');
    try {
      // Get the user object
      const { data: { user } } = await supabase.auth.getUser();
      
      if (!user) {
        console.log('User not found');
        return;
      }
  
      // Extract the user_id from the user object
      const user_id = user.id;
  
      // Query the users table using the user_id
      const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('users')
        .select('token_count')
        .eq('user_id', user_id);
  
      if (error) {
        // Handle the error if the query fails
        console.error('Error retrieving user token count:', error);
      } else {
        if (data.length > 0) {
          // A match was found, extract the token_count value
          const { token_count } = data[0];
          
          // Use the token_count value as needed
          setTokenCount(token_count); // Set the token count in the state
        } else {
          // No match was found
          console.log('Token count not found for the user.');
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle any other errors that occur
      console.error('Error retrieving user token count:', error);
    }
  };

  fetchUserTokenCount();
}, [user]); // Add user as a dependency

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar tokenCount={tokenCount} user={user}  />
          <Routes>
            <Route path = "/login" element = {<AuthPage/>} />
            <Route path = "/" element = {<LandingPage
              items={items}
              setItems={setItems}
              setFilteredItems={setFilteredItems}
              filteredItems={filteredItems}/>} />
            <Route path = "/home" element = {<HomePage
              items={items}
              setItems={setItems}
              setFilteredItems={setFilteredItems}
              filteredItems={filteredItems}
              tokenCount={tokenCount}
              setTokenCount={setTokenCount}/>} 
              />
            <Route path = "/myaccount" element = {<MyAccountPage/>} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
type here
```

I put it in a useffect as shown in code block,altered the rendering order of components in the return jsx. Could it be my sessions are being created in Authpage so when navbar is being rendered the user is still not being detected therefore taking a while for the token count to render in navbar i am also using token count in homepage and pop up. I need the correct token count to be presented as soon as the user logs in. What it is currently doing its showing the token count of the previous user who logged in and then after a refresh its updating the token count to show the current user token count value.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You could use `onAuthStateChange` callback to listen to when the user auth state changes, and fetch the user-specific information within the callback.
https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-onauthstatechange